# What does this use of the spread operator do?

Tags: javascript

I just noticed this in some code and I've been trying to understand what it is doing.

```
this.rows[rowIndex][cell] = event.target.value;
this.rows = [...this.rows];
```

It appears to me that it's simply assigning `this.rows` to itself.  Is there some other use of the spread operator in which this makes sense?  Or is it simply a bug?

Comment: It takes a shallow copy. If the original `this.rows` is array-like (iterable), but not truly an array, it will be one after the assignment.

Comment: Basically does the same thing as `this.rows = this.rows.slice()`

Comment: You have to show us more context to make sense out of this.

Comment: What is  `event.target.value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread syntax will give a shallow copy of the original array.

There are at least two reasons why this may be useful:

- Any references that exist to the original `rows` property will not be affected by later assignments made to the direct properties of the copied array.
- If the original value of `rows` was not a true array, but iterable (array-like), then the result of the spread syntax assignment will still be a true array.

Here is an artificially made object to illustrate these two points:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(n) { // Define array-like object 
        this.rows = {
            // Define iterator
            [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
                for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) yield this[i];
            },
        }
        // Create "index" properties
        for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) this.rows[i] = [];
    }
    bar(rowIndex, cell, value) {
        this.rows[rowIndex][cell] = value;
        console.log(this.rows);
        // Take shallow copy
        this.rows = [...this.rows];
        // Now it is a true array
        console.log(this.rows);
        // We add a value to that array, which other copies will not see
        this.rows.push("added");
        console.log(this.rows);
    }
}
var foo = new Foo(2); // Create array-like object
var remember = foo.rows; // get its rows
foo.bar(1, 0, 15); // set one particular value to 15
// Demonstrate that the value that was added inside the method is not in our copy
console.log(remember);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Note how the first output has the `{ }` notation: it is not recognised as a true array. The second output is with `[ ]`: a true array. The third output shows an additional value that was pushed on that array. The final output shows these manipulations (making it an array and adding a value to it) are not reflected in the original reference we had to the `rows` property.